# not finding icons in dolphin in pop os 20.04

Tags: qt, icons, pop-os, dolphin

I have installed dolphin of KDE in pop os. But I found that folder icons and back forward icons were not showing in that file manager. Looking for the solution, I found that installing qt5ct and then selecting KDE icon theme would sort out the issue. However, I am not finding that option there. So unable to get the expected results. Below I am giving a screenshot of what is being displayed in the qt5ct application. Note: My DE is still the system default GNOME.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the KDE icon set was not installed in my system. So qt5ct could not find that. So I had to install the breeze icon theme in my system and it could find the icon set. After selecting that, I had to log out to make the changes permanently. I used [this link](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/breeze-icon-theme/) to install the breeze icon theme.